# how to convert array to char, so that I can to return this char value from a function in c. then, calling it in Python. 

Tags: python, c, hash, ctypes

I want to make function, that can to return a value of string. But I got stumbled around this problem in days cannot to resolve this mistake alone. So I need your advices and hints. I was using Hash jh sha3 2010 candidate function. here is the code:

```
anyway this an update code, but I still dont get expected value to get this function called from Python Language. the returned value is "9976864". Anymore helps?

#include <stdio.h>
#include "jh_ansi_opt32.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* jh(char *input)
{
BitSequence  output[512];
char *iData; 
char* msg;

int dInt;

msg= (char*)malloc(sizeof(output));
if(!msg){
    return 1;
}

memset(output,0,sizeof(output));

iData = input;
printf("[+] data is %s\n", iData);
dInt = strlen(iData);
BitSequence data[dInt];

memset(data,0, sizeof(data));
strncpy(data,iData,dInt);
DataLength dLen =dInt;
HashJh(512, data,dLen,output);
//printf("\n[+] resulted hash is ");

int k;
for (k=0;k<sizeof(output);k++){
        msg[k]= output[k];
}
if (msg) return msg;
free(msg);
return 0;
}
```

And the python one is:

```
from ctypes import *
d = CDLL('jh.dll')
a=d.jh('this is message by hash jh function')
print a
```

This is an update code, but still dont get expected value. The retuned value when I try to call from python is something integer "9968784". Anymore helps would be appreciated, thanks..

Comment: I have no idea what this code is supposed to be doing.  You never initialise `msg`, but then you increment it in a loop, and then return it.

Comment: uhm, I still dont have good understanding between "char *var" and  "char* var".

Comment: Whoa there. You're trying to learn too many things at once. Break it down into steps. Learn arrays and pointers. Write a function that returns a pointer. Then take on malloc. A tutorial would be helpful here...

Comment: but that's the fastest way I can to grab comp sciences.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if (!(BitSequence *)malloc(sizeof(output)))
>     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
> ```

That doesn't do anything. Second, you're incrementing `msg` and **then** returning it. Third, you never seem to dereference `msg`, you're only incrementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `malloc` code, your `output`, `data`, and `dLen` arrays/variables will be allocated on the stack.

`msg` is a `char*`, not a `char`.  It is also uninitialized.

If you want to return a string, you need to allocate that using `malloc` and fill it in somehow.  Return a pointer to that for your string.

Comment: uhm, I get little confused on your said "return a pointer to that for your string" is refer to of what my variable, does "msg"?

Comment: Something like `char *msg = (char*)malloc(???);...fill in msg somehow...;return msg;`

Comment: does filling the msg by this one is acceptable "for (k=0;k<sizeof(output);k++){
   msg += output[k];
 }"

Comment: I still got returned value "9980707". By the way, I make this code to be a dll. And calling this function from Python Language.

Comment: @user1309539: no, you need to do `msg[i] = ` something.  Don't change `msg` itself.

Answer (score 0):

This either loses the pointer returned by malloc, or only works when there is no more memory:

```
if (!(BitSequence *)malloc(sizeof(output)))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Then this does the same:

```
if ((BitSequence *) malloc(sizeof(data)) == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Is that what you need? I'd normally say that is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the return value issue in Python, `ctypes` defaults to expecting an integer return value.  Tell it the return type ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#return-types)):

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> d = CDLL('jh.dll')
>>> d.jh('abc')
39727048
>>> d.jh.restype=c_char_p
>>> dll.jh('abc')
'abc'
```

I faked your DLL and just returned a string.  The number you get is the integer value of the pointer address returned.

Note as others mention you will leak memory returning a malloc'ed pointer with no way to free it.